# mutt responsive way to refresh inbox

Tags: mutt

Using `mutt` with Gmail I "check for e-mail updates" sometimes through the <kbd>$</kbd> binding (sync-mailbox), sometimes just by using <kbd>c</kbd> (change folder) and just supplying `=` (defaults to MAILBOX) as the IMAP folder path to change to.

Is there a better (in particular: faster) way of doing the same? A solution would be something that is more direct than "pretending to switch folders", as I do, for example. Also something that does not "miss" some updates, as <kbd>$</kbd> seems to do at times (perhaps <kbd>$</kbd> is not meant to check for e-mails at all but just to expunge messages marked as deleted, etc?)

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `mail_check` settings in mutt?

Comment: To be able to choose when I poll the server?

Comment: `man muttrc | less -p mail_check` - configure if/when mutt looks for new mail...

Comment: But I would like to issue the command manually, only: more conveniently than "pretending to switch IMAP folders". Most of the time, I don't need the polling at all..

Comment: `mutt` updates the folder status after [every keyboard input](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttFaq/Folder); either keep hitting `$` or bind a specific key of your choice... Personally, I'm happy with letting mutt handle it.

Comment: Really? _keep hitting_ `$`?

Comment: Well, hitting any key is sort of odd when mutt can be set up to do it automatically...

Comment: No. I don't want to waste laptop battery, network bandwidth, etc to check for e-mail when I don't need to check for it.

Comment: Its not polling the server; its just checking your maildir... Its all in the manual and FAQ I linked to.

Comment: I am confused. I thought in IMAP a connection with the server is kept open so that the server may send unsolicited commands to clients over it... [compare/contrast NOOP (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.1.2) Vs receiving untagged EXISTS and RECENT] anyway, I just need a "check mail" "button".

Comment: Some imap servers have agressive timeout settings and will drop the connection if you spend more than a minute or so reading (or replying) to an email.  I ran into this issue with the Exchange server at work and ended up giving up on using mutt as an imap client...used fetchmail (using procmail as mda) instead.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Bind a key (`G` for "Get" is recommended) to `imap-fetch-mail` in your ~/.muttrc.

```
 bind index G imap-fetch-mail
```

Pressing `G` while in the index will now fetch new mail from the imap server.

(for POP users, the `fetch-mail` function fetches mail from a POP server)

Comment: Looks great... could I run this as a simple command, without the binding? How? (thanks a lot for your answer, BTW)

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the question.  what do you mean by "run this as a simple command"?

Comment: @Robottinosino You can run the command without binding it to a key with `M-x` (i.e. `Alt+X` or `ESC x`): `M-x imap-fetch-mail RET`.

Comment: Both `Meta_L+x` and `Alt_L+x` give me: `Key is not bound.  Press '?' for help`.

Comment: Alright, I surrender to some sort of binding and will use: `macro index,pager ,f "<imap-fetch-mail>"`

Comment: To do it unbound, just type `:exec imap-fetch-mail`. But that won’t refresh anything when `mutt` thinks it’s in sync with the server but really is not (this seems to happen if you use another client to edit the mailbox and after editing the count of messages in the mailbox has not changed (e.g., delete+receive new mail)).

Answer (score 17):

You can set the `timeout` variable to something like:

```
set timeout=10
```

This will poll the current mailbox every 10 seconds at most when mutt is idle waiting for user input, more often than the default 600 seconds.
This is not needed in post v1.5.11 when IDLE is enabled.